# Search longest path in JSON

Tags: javascript, ruby, json

I am wondering if there is a quick way to find the solution of getting longest path in the JSON below. The result should be 4 or ["Phnom Penh", "Doun Penh", "Phsa Thmey", "Phsa Thmey One"]

```
{
"name": "Phnom Penh",
"code": "PP",
"sub": [
    {
        "name": "Reousey Keo",
        "code": "RK",
        "sub": {
            "name": "Toul Sangke",
            "code": "TSK"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Doun Penh",
        "code": "DP",
        "sub": {
            "name": "Phsa Thmey",
            "code": "PT",
            "sub": {
                "name": "Phsa Thmey One",
                "code": "PTO"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Mean Chey",
        "code": "MC",
        "sub": {
            "name": "Nerot",
            "code": "NR"
        }
    }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Kandal",
    "code": "KD"
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in JavaScript, or in Ruby? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: sounds like you are asking for others to code this for you. Where's your attempt?

Comment: I have tried to loop it and since this one is a small piece of JSON then it would not take much time. My real JSON much larger than this and it take a lot of time. so i am wondering if there is pattern to solve that problem. I am using ruby but answer as JS is fine

Comment: And by quick, you mean easy to program, or fast to execute?

Comment: Fast execute is what I concern

Answer (score 1):

This recursive approach should work with any nesting of arrays and hashes (though I suspect it could be simplified some). Here I've assumed there is nothing special about the key `:sub`, so the code would work with (for example) the fragment:

```
{
  name: "Doun Penh",
  code: "DP",
  hub: {
    name: "Toledo" }
    code: "TOL"
  }
  bub: {
    name: "Phsa Thmey",
    code: "PT",
    dub: {
      name: "Phsa Thmey One",
      code: "PTO"
    }
  }
}
```

The code below operates on an array that is constructed from the JSON string.

**Code**

```
def deepest(obj, key, dsf={ depth: 0, path: [] })
  dsf_below = dsf.dup
  case obj
  when Array
   obj.each_with_index do |o,i|
     d = deepest(o, key, { depth: dsf[:depth], path: dsf[:path] + [i] } )
     if d[:depth] > dsf_below[:depth]
       dsf_below = d
     end
   end
  when Hash
   if obj.key?(key)
     dkey = { depth: dsf[:depth]+1, path: dsf[:path] + [obj[key]] }
     if dkey[:depth] > dsf_below[:depth]
       dsf_below = dkey
     end
     obj.each do |k,v|
       if (v.is_a? Array) || (v.is_a? Hash)
         d = deepest(v, key, { depth: dkey[:depth], path: dkey[:path] + [k] } )
         if d[:depth] > dsf_below[:depth]
           dsf_below = d
         end
       end
     end
   end
  end
  dsf_below
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [
  {
    name: "Phnom Penh",
    code: "PP",
    sub: [
      { 
        name: "Reousey Keo",
        code: "RK",
        dub: {
          name: "Toul Sangke",
          code: "TSK" } },
      {
        name: "Doun Penh",
        code: "DP",
        bub: {
          name: "Phsa Thmey",
          code: "PT",
          gub: {
            name: "Phsa Thmey One",
            code: "PTO" } } },
      {
        name: "Mean Chey",
        code: "MC",
        hub: {
          name: "Nerot",
          code: "NR" } } ] },
  {
    name: "Kandal",
    code: "KD" } ]

deepest(arr, :name)
  #=> {:depth=>4, :path=>[0, "Phnom Penh", :sub, 1, "Doun Penh",
  #    :bub, "Phsa Thmey", :gub, "Phsa Thmey One"]}
```